# Regression for 3 levels dependent variable

Tags: regression, categorical-data, repeated-measures, multinomial-logit

While reviewing a paper, I came across the following problem:
the authors tested two groups, let's call them A and B, in two different experimental conditions, X and Y. The outcome variable had three non-ordinal, nominal levels: a,b and c. If the subjects responded 'a' that was considered the correct or expected answer, and b and c were inaccurate answers. The authors count the number of responses that fell into each one of the three categories. Each subject was tested in both conditions. To sum up, we have the following:

- Independent variables: conditions X and Y and group A and B;
- Dependent variable: nominal with three possible outcomes, a,b and c;
- Random factors: subject and items of each condition

The authors want to know if the conditions X and Y elicit a different proportion of accurate responses, and whether group A had a worse performance than group B. In order to answer the question, the authors used generalized linear mixed-effect models, which, I guess, were like this (using R):

```r
    glmer(accuracy ~ condition + group + (1|subject) + (1|item), data = data)
    glmer(accuracy ~ condition + (1|subject) + (1|item), data = data)
    glmer(accuracy ~ group + (1|subject) + (1|item), data = data)
```

Model 2 was chosen based on Akaike.

One thing, though, I didn't get: they conducted three separate analyses for each level of the dependent variable. In the first one, they considered the count of 'a' as the dependent variable, in the second one, the count of 'b', and in the third one, the count of 'c'. In all the three analyses, they verified the difference between condition X and Y and between group A and B. That seems odd to me. I have the following question:

1. I think it would make more sense to consider a model with all the possible outcomes as a dependent variable. Could a multinomial logistic regression work in this case? Can this kind of regression be used for repeated-measures?
2. Would the model the authors adopted be justified in any circumstance?

Comment: Multinomial logistic regression could be a better choice. Search this site, and specifically tags [tag:multinomial-logit] and [tag:mlogit]